# MYSQL 5.1.51-community Stored Procedure with if statement

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to make a routine (Stored procedure on MySQL 5.1.51-community version) that updating the user number when the user is on first access to website

this is the routine

```
BEGIN

-- first routine
UPDATE `tbl_1` q
JOIN (
    SELECT
        m.UserNumber,
        m.sUpdate
    FROM
        `tbl_1` t
    JOIN `tbl_2` m ON t.UserNumber = m.UserNumber
    WHERE
        t.UserDate IS NULL
) x
SET q.UserNumber = x.UserNumber
WHERE
    q.UserNumber = x.UserNumber
AND x.sUpdate IS NULL;

-- second routine
UPDATE `tbl_2` q
JOIN (
    SELECT
        m.UserNumber,
        m.sUpdate
    FROM
        `tbl_1` t
    JOIN `tbl_2` m ON t.UserNumber = m.UserNumber
) x
SET q.sUpdate = 1
WHERE
    q.UserNumber = x.UserNumber;

END
```

but i need execute the `-- second routine` only when the `-- first routine` actually updated a row on `tbl_1`

Thanks for all the help!

**UPDATE #2**

```
BEGIN

SET @LastUpdateUserNumber := NULL;

-- first routine
UPDATE `tbl_1` q
JOIN (
    SELECT
        m.UserNumber,
        m.sUpdate
    FROM
        `tbl_1` t
    JOIN `tbl_2` m ON t.UserNumber = m.UserNumber
    WHERE
        t.UserDate IS NULL
) x
SET q.UserNumber = x.UserNumber,
    q.UserNumber = (SELECT @LastUpdateUserNumber := x.UserNumber)
WHERE
    q.UserNumber = x.UserNumber
AND x.sUpdate IS NULL;

SELECT @LastUpdateUserNumber AS LastUpdateUserNumber;

IF ROW_COUNT() THEN
-- second routine
UPDATE `tbl_2` q
SET q.sUpdate = 1
WHERE
    q.UserNumber = (SELECT @LastUpdateUserNumber);

END IF;

END
```

**UPDATE**

```
BEGIN

-- first routine
UPDATE `tbl_1` q
JOIN (
    SELECT
        m.UserNumber,
        m.sUpdate
    FROM
        `tbl_1` t
    JOIN `tbl_2` m ON t.UserNumber = m.UserNumber
    WHERE
        t.UserDate IS NULL
) x
SET q.UserNumber = x.UserNumber
WHERE
    q.UserNumber = x.UserNumber
AND x.sUpdate IS NULL;

IF ROW_COUNT() THEN
-- second routine
UPDATE `tbl_2` q
JOIN (
    SELECT
        m.UserNumber,
        m.sUpdate
    FROM
        `tbl_1` t
    JOIN `tbl_2` m ON t.UserNumber = m.UserNumber
) x
SET q.sUpdate = 1
WHERE
    q.UserNumber = x.UserNumber;

END IF;

END
```

Comment: `IF ROW_COUNT() THEN` ?

Comment: @Akina any example please?

Comment: I cannot - the User Manual for MySQL 5.1 was removed from official MySQL site. And none online fiddle supports this version.

Comment: That version is prehistoric. I doubt you'll be able to find someone who remembers what the differences were.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On version 5.5+ this may be:

```sql
BEGIN
    -- first routine
    IF ROW_COUNT() THEN
        -- second routine
    END IF;
END
```

Test... maybe this is applicable to your version.

---

### UPDATE

I find the copy of the manual for 5.1 version (http://www.mysql.ru/docs/mysql-man-5.1-en/). It claims that ROW_COUNT() function was introduced at 5.0.1, so the above code must work correctly.

Comment: thanks i have tried your suggestion, please see **update** in my first question. the table 1 is updated but is not updated table 2

Comment: @Kooper Updated code MUST work. The only thing - 2nd table will be updated only when 1st table is updated ACTUALLY. For example, the value 1 updated with value 2. If value 1 is updated with the same value 1 - this is not actual update, and 2nd query will not be executed in this case. If you need to update 2nd table during such fake update too then use IF EXISTS with the query which checks that the joining condition in 1st query returns rows.

Comment: thanks i think solve... please see **update 2** in my first question... this routine updated the data basis on last updated table username.